# Qt application that uses CUDA runtime libraries does not run when double-clicking

Tags: qt, cuda

I'm learning to build Qt + CUDA applications on linux (Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit). For starters, I am trying to build an application that checks the number of CUDA enabled devices on my computer.

I am able to launch the application from within Qt Creator but not by double clicking on the app. I can run it by issuing ./device_query in the terminal (the name of the app is device_query).

I have a simple UI (the default created by Qt Creator when a Qt gui app is created)

Here are the other files

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;


};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    int count;
    cudaGetDeviceCount(&count); //when this line is added, unable to double click and launch

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QtDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

.pro file

```
QT       += core gui
TARGET = device_query
TEMPLATE = app

HEADERS = mainwindow.h
SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp
FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/cuda/include

LIBS += -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64/ -lcudart
```

Why is it that I am not able to run the application by double clicking it?

Comment: And if you remove all the CUDA related code, the application runs fine in either case?

Comment: @Bart Yes. If I compile with the line __cudaGetDeviceCount(&count)__ removed, I can launch the application by double clicking it.

Comment: What (if any) error does the call to cudaGetDeviceCount return? Might there be a privilege issue?

Comment: @Bart There is no error. As I explained in the question the difference is only in being able to launch by double clicking. I am able to run the application from terminal (./device_query) if the line is in the program

Comment: Given that the CUDA query makes all the difference (according to you) something possibly fails in that call. Given that you perform the query in the constructor of your MainWindow, the application might actually run, but you don't get to see anything when it fails. Anyway, that's just my guess. If that's not the case, someone else might have a better idea. Good luck. :)

Comment: hmmm...though I am getting the correct value of count? I think I will post the project and upload somewhere and give the link in my post (not sure if this is allowed on stackoverflow though!)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11954/discussion-between-mathai-and-bart)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is probably with $LD_LIBRARY_PATH not being set for the application when it is launched by double-click. In Nsight Eclipse Edition we have a shell script that initializes the environment and then starts the IDE - this way you can start Nsight from the desktop menus.